# Why didn't Margaery follow her grandmother's plan?

Tags: game-of-thrones

(Season 6 spoilers)

> Why didn't Margaery just let the Tyrell army take on the Faith Militant, and free her and Loras?
>
>  Even if her plan succeeded, it would have resulted in Loras being ruined and the Tyrells left without an heir

Comment: I believe she feared for her brother's life if there was bloodshed, among other things.

Answer (score 5):

To expound on System Down's answer, there's also the aspect that she was a full player in the Game of Thrones.  It would be the Tyrells taking the risks, the Tyrells turning the mob, formerly friendly towards Margaery, against the Tyrells, it puts their family at risk of becoming targets in a war with fanatics.

Cersei would reap many of the benefits.  Instead, by Margaery pretending to be converted and getting the Faith Militant on their side, Cersei becomes isolated, Tommen is under her influence, mostly, while gaining popular appeal and some degree of independence from his mother (but not Margaery), and then the sham trial would have seen Cersei further humiliated and de-powered.

Margaery was trying to outflank and isolate her main, hated rival, not just escape confinement.

Comment: In one word: Smallfolk!

Answer (score 3):

Because if Mace Tyrell had taken on the Faith Militant it would be very bad for the Tyrells. The High Sparrow and his Faith Militant are a grass roots movement. They were created and are supported by the commoners *despite* the will of the nobles. This makes antagonizing the High Sparrow a very dangerous course of action for any noble house, but especially the Tyrells.

Ever since they rescued King's Landing from Stannis, the good reputation that House Tyrell enjoys has been through the good will of the commoners. They broke the siege, brought in food and treated the poor charitably. This good will is part of the reason they are in power. To openly fight the Faith Militant would shatter all that good will, and risk open rebellion by the common people.